# C# Windows Application Programming: index all files from folder and play at random with my default application?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to index every music file in a folder and play them at random (without repeating) with the default application on my system. For example: 
 ogg - itunes
 mp3 - WMP
 mp4 - quicktime
Are there tutorials that will help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, once you have a list of files, if you want to come up with a (pseudo)-random permutation of them, what you want is a shuffle algorithm, like [Knuth-Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

If you have a single filename and you want to open it with the default application, you can probably use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(mp3FileName);
```

See also the [MSDN documentation on Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326951%28VS.71%29.aspx).

This will behave equivalently to just double-clicking on the files in whatever order the shuffle comes up with.  Depending on your media player, that may be good enough.  However, unless you somehow know how long each media file is, you won't know how long to wait before starting the next one, and I don't think there's any way to wait for the music player to finish playing the media file without having special-case code specific to each player.

You may be able to use the Verb property of the ProcessStartInfo object to select "Enqueue" or something similar, which may do exactly what you want.  Again, MSDN has some additional [information on ProcessStartInfo.Verb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb%28VS.71%29.aspx) that may be helpful to you.